# I have a SimpleScalar. I need its String's getBytes() return value. What can I do?

Tags: freemarker

I have, in my Freemarker template, a `SimpleScalar`.

I need to get the return value of its underlying `String`'s `getBytes()` method.  Is there any way to do this in Freemarker Template Language?

Comment: What's that needed for?

Comment: Long story.  Short version is base64 encoding in a context where I can neither affect the data model nor the Freemarker configuration.

Comment: I found a way to do it (assume statics is in your data model): `<#assign contentsAsByteBuffer = statics["java.nio.charset.Charset"].forName("UTF-8").encode(‌​scalar).rewind()>
<#assign contentsAsByteArray = contentsAsByteBuffer.array()[0..<contentsAsByteBuffer.limit()]>`

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to write a `TemplateMethodModelEx` for that, and then either expose that via Java by adding it to `Configuration.sharedVariables`, or by `#import`/`#include` and `<#assign utf8Byes = 'com.example.freemarker.MyUTF8BytesMethod'?new()>` in the included/imported template. Then you do something like `utf8Bytes(someString)` in the templates.

Another solution is using static models as you did in your comment.